# Does performBlockAndWait always done on the same thread

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I did this for experiment.

Well, if it's not on the same thread, the @syhcronized will cause deadlock. So far it doesn't.

I just need confirmation.

```
@synchronized([BGFetchClass class])
{
    [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
        @synchronized([BGFetchClass class])
        {
            saveSuccesfully = [moc save:&error];
            if (!saveSuccesfully) {
                CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: What concurrency type did you create the MOC with?

Comment: This question is more direct. Moreover the answers on those questions are not clear. Some says it run on the same thread. Some says it runs on the main thread (which may not be the same thread with the calling thread). THe official position is that it "doesn't matter". So which one is right?